# Facebook Open Graph Object link

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I succesfully posted a OG action to my app timeline on facebook. Now however when i click the object title it just opens the url where facebook gets the data for the open graph action. I want to add a custom url to my website. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is by design.  If you need a user to go to your website after he clicks on the OG action, then on the page that represents the action, add a JavaScript redirect `location.href= 'URL to your site';`